# How create a collection instance with python

Tags: python, instances, collections

Hi how create a collection instance with Python code example ([How to avoid operator `collection_instance_add`?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156473/how-to-avoid-operator-collection-instance-addbut)) this code does not work I not can link this instance to the collection
Error

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\script.blend\Text", line 13, in <module>
RuntimeError: Error: Object 'my_new__obj_instance_name' already in collection 
'the_name_of_the_collection_to_use'
```

code not work

```
source_collection =   bpy.data.collections["the_name_of_the_collection_to_use"]
instance_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(
name="my_new__obj_instance_name", 
object_data=None
)
instance_obj.instance_collection = source_collection
instance_obj.instance_type = 'COLLECTION'
parent_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection# not work
parent_collection.collection.objects.link(instance_obj) # not work
```

I need an alternative command bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add

Comment: Hello, please post your script in its entirety, this error is most likely caused by you already linking the object to this collection previously. Also, it doesn't make sense to put a collection instance in the collection it is instancing. You risk breaking the fabric of reality and creating a black hole because of an infinite recursion

Comment: I want to create a collection instance bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add

Comment: As stated in the second part of my comment, you can not link a collection instance in the collection it is instancing, that would create an infinite recursion loop. Click on another collection in the outliner to make it active before executing the script